# When a semi-ring which contains a union?

Tags: measure-theory

In what follows $\bigsqcup$ denotes disjoint union. I have marked the point where I don't understand the reasoning with (WHY).

In the proof([Measures integrals and martingales](http://books.google.com/books?id=_OjSIphIrH0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=measures%20integrals%https://math.stackexchange.com/questions20martingales&hl=en&sa=X&ei=E4rRUqCcCKTE0QXbyYDwBg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=measures%20integrals%20martingales&f=false) starts p 39)(step 2): the following set is defined $\mathcal S_\cup=\{S_1 \sqcup S_2 \ldots \sqcup S_M : M\in \Bbb{N}, S_j \in \mathcal S \}$ where $\mathcal S$ is a [semi ring](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Semiring_of_Sets). Now let the collection of sets $(T_k)_{k\in \Bbb{N}} \subset  \mathcal S_\cup$ be pairwise disjoint such that $T:= \bigsqcup_{k \in \Bbb{N}}T_k \in \mathcal S_\cup$.  It can be shown that $\mathcal S_\cup$ is a [ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets). (Not sure how this will help)

By the definition of $\mathcal S_\cup$ we find $(S_k)_{k\in \Bbb{N}}\subset \mathcal S$ and a sequence of integers $0=n(0)\le n(1) \le n(2) \le \dots$ such that $$T_k=S_{n(k-1)+1} \sqcup \ldots \sqcup S_{n(k)}$$ and  $T=U_1 \sqcup \ldots \sqcup U_N$ where $\displaystyle U_l=\bigsqcup_{j\in J_l}S_j \in \mathcal S$(WHY?) with disjoint index sets $J_1 \sqcup J_2\ldots \sqcup J_N= \Bbb{N}$ that partition $\Bbb{N}$.

I was thinking since $T \in \mathcal S_\cup$ then $T=S'_1 \sqcup \ldots S'_M$ where $S'_i \in \mathcal S$ but I can't go anywhere from here.( I can't figue out a way to relate thes $S'_i$ to $U_i$)

Comment: This seems not to be true, as you write that $T \in S_{\cup} $ so $T$ is a disjoint union of finitely many sets from $S$. Butat the end, it seems to be that $T$ is equal to the disjoint union of $S_1, S_2, ... , S_n, ...$ as the $J_k$ partition $\mathbb{N}$. Something must be wrong.

Comment: I seem to have abused $S_i$ and used it wrongly in my thoughts, are you saying what is above my ideas is wrong?

Comment: I say that the claim, where you said: "(WHY?)" is inconsistent with the definition of $T$.

Comment: @DanielSoltész those are the author's words(word for word). The way $T$ is defined is to be an infinite union of disjoint sets in $\mathcal S_\cup$ which still remains in $\mathcal S_\cup$. Now what I'm thinking is that due to the fact that that union remains in $\mathcal S_\cup$ then it can be expressed as a finite union of sets in $\mathcal S$ due to the way $\mathcal S_\cup$ is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with the notation, there is no reason for $U_l=\bigsqcup_{j\in J_l}S_j $ for those particular $S_j$,  however $U_l$ is a union of some sets in $\mathcal S$ which will still allow you to continue with the proof that the measure is $\sigma$-additive(that's how I did it when I got to it).

As you said since $T\in \mathcal S_\cup$ then we have disjoint $U_i\in \mathcal S$ such that $T=U_1 \sqcup \ldots \sqcup U_N$ and since $T_k \in \mathcal S_\cup$, $T_k=S^k_1 \sqcup \ldots \sqcup S^k_{M_k}$ and define $S^k_q=\emptyset$ for all $q > M_k$ (I prefer writing the $S$ in this manner to avoid the whole sequence of integers issue). Also define $Y^{l,k}_i =U_i\cap S^k_l$. Note that $Y^{l,k}_i \in \mathcal S$ since it is the intersection of two sets in a semi-ring. We have
$$U_i= U_i \cap T=U_i \cap_{} (\bigsqcup_{(k,l)\in \Bbb{N}^2} S^k_l )=\bigsqcup_{(k,l)\in \Bbb{N}^2} (U_i \cap S^k_l) =\bigsqcup_{(k,l)\in \Bbb{N}^2}Y^{l,k}_i  $$ 
hence $U_i$ is disjoint union of sets in $\mathcal S$( the union can be changed to become over $\Bbb N$ since $ \#\Bbb{N}=\#\Bbb{N}^2$). To see how you can continue the proof: $$S^k_l=S^k_l \cap T= S^k_l \cap \bigsqcup_{i=1}^NU_i=\bigsqcup_{i=1}^N (S^k_l \cap U_i)= \bigsqcup_{i=1}^N  Y^{l,k}_i $$

$\mu(U_i)=\mu(\bigsqcup _{k \in \Bbb{N}}\bigsqcup _{l \in \Bbb{N}}  Y^{l,k}_i )\overset{\sigma\text{-advty}}{=}\sum _{k \in \Bbb{N}}\sum _{l \in \Bbb{N}}  \mu(Y^{l,k}_i)$ and $\mu(S^k_l)=\sum_{i=1}^N\mu(Y^{l,k}_i)$, which give $$\sum_{i=1}^N\mu(U_i)=\sum_{i=1}^N\sum _{k \in \Bbb{N}}\sum _{l \in \Bbb{N}}  \mu(Y^{l,k}_i)=\sum _{k \in \Bbb{N}}\sum _{l \in \Bbb{N}}  \mu(S_l^k)$$

We also have by definition $\bar \mu(T)=\sum_{i=1}^N\mu(U_i)$ and $\bar \mu(T_k)=\sum_{l\in \Bbb N}\mu(S^k_l)$ then $\sum_{k \in \Bbb N}\bar \mu(T_k)=\sum_{k \in \Bbb N}\sum_{l\in \Bbb N}\mu(S^k_l)=\sum_{i=1}^N\mu(U_i)=\bar \mu(T)$.